# How to extract only String part from a column containing alphanumeric String in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a alphaNumeric column in my mysql Database like this `INV0001` and many values like `INVI000040`  where alphabets can be of variable length and integers can be of variable length. I want to extract only the alphabetic string from this column . I have searched on google I found about PATINDEX but that is not available in mysql . Please give some hint related to this problem . I am not able to understand how to do this.

Comment: You can't easily do this in MySQL.  Can you tell anything about the first digit after the last alpha character?  Or, could that digit be anything?

Comment: No first alpha and last alpha and that digits could be anything

Comment: What about the alpha leading component?  Do you know how many characters that might be?

Comment: No it can be any number of components

Comment: it can be any number of characters

Comment: There is no easy solution, but I will post something you can try using immediately.

Comment: Suppose I have 2 or three alphabets and numbers of various length then is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does have any native regex replacement support, at least not of the time this answer was written.  However, if you just want the letter components, you may try just removing all digits:

```
SELECT
    col,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(col, '9', ''), '8', ''), '7', ''), '6', ''), '5', ''), '4', ''),
         '3', ''), '2', ''), '1', ''), '0', '') AS alpha_only
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Ok thanks let me try now  I have convert this query in sequelize

Comment: @Vikas If you can't figure out how to do that, there should be an option in your framework for running raw MySQL queries.  While you should ideally not have to do that, this might be a good reason/exception.